# When there are multiple "enters the battlefield" effects but "lasts until end of turn" is said once, do they all last until end of turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, [Cavalry Drillmaster](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCavalry%20Drillmaster%5d) has two *enters the battlefield* effects separated with an *and*:

> When Cavalry Drillmaster enters the battlefield, target creature gets +2/+0 and gains first strike until end of turn.

Do both effects last until the end of the turn or just *first strike*? Where is this defined in the rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They **all** last until the end of the turn, not just first strike. Since it's hard to keep track of these abilities for a longer period, *permanent* boosts (or curses) almost always use 'counters', like a +1/+1 counter, which stay on the card as a visible representation. (There are a handful of exceptions like [Figure of Destiny](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373388).)

So if the +2/+0 boost would be permanent, it would have read something like this:

> When Cavalry Drillmaster enters the battlefield, choose target creature. Put a +2/+0 on that creature. That creature gains first strike until end of turn.

Note that the effect has now been split in two sentences, to indicate the difference in duration.